# Get age from birth date PL/SQL (implicit cursor), with dbms_output.put_line

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table "owners" containing multiple rows of the 3 columns I want down below:

```
name, varchar2 
sName, varchar2 
birthDate, varchar2(13) written like 'YYYYMMDD-XXXX' (I later delete the 5 last characters, [edit: not allowed to change from varchar])
```

I want to calculate the age of the people in the table and present it like this:

```
John, Johnson, 55,5 years.
Allen, McAllen, 43,6 years.
Etc, Etc, Etc...
Etc, Etc, Etc...
```

I have tried probably 100 different combinations to calculate the age. But I can't figure it out so here you get the base code without sysdate etc.:

```
declare
cursor c_ownersList is select name, sName, substr(birthDate, 1, 8) as newBiDate
                        from owners; 
begin
    for rec in c_ownersList loop
        dbms_output.put_line(initcap(rec.name)||', '||initcap(rec.sName)||', '||rec.newBiDate);
    end loop;
    end;
```

**SO: How do I calculate the age?**

Comment: Store dates as proper DATE types, not VARCHAR. That is bad, bad, bad.  Please edit the question and show complete and exact sample data for the "owners" table.

Comment: This is the thing. I'm not allowed to change data type. Maybe I should have said that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the substring you have to a date, use `months_between()` to get the number of months, divide that by 12, and round or (more likely) truncate that:

```
        dbms_output.put_line(initcap(rec.name)||', '
            ||initcap(rec.sName) ||', '
            ||trunc(months_between(sysdate, to_date(rec.newBiDate, 'YYYYMMDD'))/12, 1));
```

So in full, keeping your cursor as it is:

```
declare
cursor c_ownersList is select name, sName, substr(birthDate, 1, 8) as newBiDate
                        from owners; 
begin
    for rec in c_ownersList loop
        dbms_output.put_line(initcap(rec.name)||', '
            ||initcap(rec.sName) ||', '
            ||trunc(months_between(sysdate, to_date(rec.newBiDate, 'YYYYMMDD'))/12, 1));
    end loop;
end;
/
```

which gives:

```
John, Johnson, 55.5
Allen, Mcallen, 43.6
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=70e4d10e2be47a74f5a38411cc8d7d12), including a query to show the stages of the calculation.

If you want a specific decimal separator (i.e. a comma) then use `to_char()` with a format mask; otherwise it will use your session settings.

And, as already said, you should really not be storing dates as strings; if the -XXXX part is useful then store it separately.

Comment: This was really helpful and solved the problem nice and clean, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Your first HUGE mistake is to store birthdate along with some other info in a `varchar2` datatype column. Split them. Store dates in `DATE` datatype columns. Who says that someone won't enter your "birthdate" as `'ab2348xe-2345'`? How will you convert it to a valid date?

Anyway, here you go:

```
SQL> select * From owners;

NAME   BIRTHDATE
------ -------------
Little 20200420-xxxx
Foot   20051204-yyyy

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_age number;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select name, birthdate from owners) loop
  5      l_age := round(months_between(sysdate,
  6                                    to_date(substr(cur_r.birthdate, 1, 8), 'yyyymmdd')
  7                                   ) / 12, 1);
  8      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.name ||', '|| l_age ||' years');
  9    end loop;
 10  end;
 11  /
Little, 1 years
Foot, 15,4 years

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- extracts date out of the `birthdate` column
- use `months_between` function; one parameter is today's date (`sysdate`)
- divide number of months by 12 (as there are 12 months in a year)
- round the number to 1 decimal (as your example shows so)

Answer (score 1):

something like this:

```
with test_data as ( select '19630701' birthdate from dual )
select round( (sysdate-to_date(birthdate,'YYYYMMDD'))/365,1) 
 from test_data
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, fix the data model. **DO not** store birthDate as a string. Always store it and every date column in your entire database ***as Date*** (or timestamp if fractions of a second or timezone is required). You can the get age by the expression

```
floor(sysdate-birth_date)/365.242199).
```

Subtracting the dates gives the number of days as a floating point value, then divide by the number of days in a year. The floor function then drops the decimals giving Age as integer.

Answer (score 0):

Alex Poole's answer was great. I also managed to solve it like this:

```
  declare
    cursor c_ownerslist is select name, sname, 
(sysdate - to_date(substr(birtdDate, 1, 8), 'YYYYMMDD'))/365 as age
                            from owners;
    begin
        for rec in c_ownerslist loop
            dbms_output.put_line(initcap(rec.name)||', '
                ||initcap(rec.sname) ||', '
                ||trunc(rec.age, 1)||' years.');
        end loop;
    end;
```

Comment: Sure, putting the calculation in the cursor query is fine. But years don't always have 365 days so getting the months and diving by 12 is more accurate; and trunc seems more suitable than round here. When you say how old you are, do you round up? If someone was 17 years and 9 months old I'd say they were 17, not 18; and if they were 17 years and 9 months and 25 days old I'd say 17 years and 9 months, not 17 years and 10 months. (But maybe that's a cultural thing I'm not aware of...)

Comment: Hmm, in Sweden we would also say 17 years. Same when month is specified. So you are right; trunc is better suited.

Comment: To make it as clean as possible I also could have put the `trunc` function in the cursor aswell.  And divide by 365.242199 as @Belayer said to get it more right.